# Python Pandas: Append column value, based on another same column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I  have a pandas dataframe like this.

```
   Time                      Source Level  County  Town
0  2021-12-01 10:01:41.443   NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
1                      NaN   Test   3      C1      C1-T1
2                      NaN   Test   5-     C2      C2-T0
3                      NaN   Test   5-     C2      C2-T1
4  2021-12-01 10:01:46.452   NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
```

I want to append Town value, which is based on row have the same Source, Level and County value.

I have tried isin, groupby, diff(but my value is str), but still not figure out.

Image below is what I want to get.

```
   Time                      Source Level  County  Town
0  2021-12-01 10:01:41.443   NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
1                      NaN   Test   3      C1      C1-T0
2                      NaN   Test   5-     C2      C2-T0, C2-T1
3  2021-12-01 10:01:46.452   NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
```

Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way we can make this work is by creating a list out of it using `groupby()` and `apply(list)`, we can then transform this into a string separated by comma. Let's split it into 2 steps for better understanding.

Personally I would keep this data as a list within a pandas series and not do step 2. Formatting as string separated by comma might not be ideal to work with.

Step 1:

```
output = df.groupby(['Time','Source','Level','County'])['Town'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Returns:

```
                      Time Source Level County            Town
0  2021-12-01 10:01:41.443    NaN   NaN    NaN           [nan]
1  2021-12-01 10:01:46.452    NaN   NaN    NaN           [nan]
2                      NaN   Test     3     C1         [C1-T1]
3                      NaN   Test    5-     C2  [C2-T0, C2-T1]
```

Now, we can format them correctly into strings (step 2):

```
output['Town'] = pd.Series([', '.join([y for y in x if type(y) == str]) for x in output['Town']]).replace('',np.nan)
```

Which outputs our desired result:

```
                      Time Source Level County          Town
0  2021-12-01 10:01:41.443    NaN   NaN    NaN           NaN
1  2021-12-01 10:01:46.452    NaN   NaN    NaN           NaN
2                      NaN   Test     3     C1         C1-T1
3                      NaN   Test    5-     C2  C2-T0, C2-T1
```

Comment: OK, I understand. I'll try it. But I think I don't need to groupby the Time, right? Because row 1-3 is the same Time as row 0, and I want the Time value disappear(only appear in first row).

Comment: You need to use `Time` if you want your expected output, otherwise you will have 3 rows as output, not 4. But feel free to modify the code to fit your purpose.

Comment: Happy to help! If you have any questions let me know :) Also feel free to accept the answer with the tick mark in the left. It will mark your question as solved and reward with some score too!

Comment: I use groupby with "Time", but it returned empty dataframe. Also, I need dataframe sort like origin orders... Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm I'm not too sure about the first issue. To sort a dataframe you can use `.sort_values(by=['Column 1','Column 2'])`

Comment: Is this issue? https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3729